# Obtener valores de mi token con netCore 2.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, jwt, .net-core

Tengo mi token con la siguiente informacion.

[image: Captura de TOEKN]

Ahora, Area puede tener varias areas, hasta 3 o 4. Igualmente las workstation.

Yo lo que quiero es obtener esos arreglos y asignaros a unas variables. Tengo pocas semanas con netCore, aun no se como se manejan muchas cosas. Ni las formas correctas de hacerlo.

Necesito obtener esos valores para mandarlos como parametros de ciertas rutas de la API.

Agradezco cualquier orientación.

Dejo el codigo de como agrego los claims al token.

```
private async Task<IActionResult> LoginBuildTokenAsync(UserModel userInfo, string[] ciltsPathByUser, AreasByUserOnToken[] areasByUser, WorkstationsByUserOnToken[] workstationsByUser)
        {
            //Este metodo se lanza cuando queremos crear roles o asignar usuarios a ciertos roles.
            //await CreateAndAssignRoles( _serviceProvider);

            List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();

            claims.Add(new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()) );
            claims.Add(new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, userInfo.Email));
            claims.Add(new Claim("UserNumber", userInfo.UserNumber.ToString()));
            claims.Add(new Claim("UserName", userInfo.UserName.ToString()));
            claims.Add(new Claim("UserRole", userInfo.Role));

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Llave_super_secreta"]));
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var expiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1);

            JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken(
               issuer: "cosascosas.com",
               audience: "cosascosas.com",
               claims: claims,
               expires: expiration,
               signingCredentials: creds);

            token.Payload["CiltsPath"] = ciltsPathByUser;
            token.Payload["Area"] = areasByUser;
            token.Payload["Workstation"] = workstationsByUser;


            Console.Out.WriteLine();
            return Ok(new
            {
                token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                expiration = expiration
            });
        }
```

Update:
Esto es lo que me llega en el debug.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Update2:
Como me sugirieron en comentarios, agrego mis areas/workstation/ciltspath como json, los serializo y se agrega.
La cosa es que sigue sin aparecer en mis claims. Agrego imagen de como esta llegando y el codigo de como los agrego.

```
private async Task<IActionResult> LoginBuildTokenAsync(UserModel userInfo, string[] ciltsPathByUser, AreasByUserOnToken[] areasByUser, WorkstationsByUserOnToken[] workstationsByUser)
        {
            //Este metodo se lanza cuando queremos crear roles o asignar usuarios a ciertos roles.
            //await CreateAndAssignRoles( _serviceProvider);



            List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();

            claims.Add(new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()) );
            claims.Add(new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, userInfo.Email));
            claims.Add(new Claim("UserNumber", userInfo.UserNumber.ToString()));
            claims.Add(new Claim("UserName", userInfo.UserName.ToString()));
            claims.Add(new Claim("UserRole", userInfo.Role));
            claims.Add(new Claim("Area", new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(areasByUser)));
            claims.Add(new Claim("Workstation", new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(workstationsByUser)));
            claims.Add(new Claim("Ciltpath", new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ciltsPathByUser)));

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Llave_super_secreta"]));
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var expiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1);

            JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken(
               issuer: "cosas.com",
               audience: "cosas.com",
               claims: claims,
               expires: expiration,
               signingCredentials: creds);

            //token.Payload["CiltsPath"] = ciltsPathByUser;
            //token.Payload["Area"] = areasByUser;
            //token.Payload["Workstation"] = workstationsByUser;

            return Ok(new
            {
                token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                expiration = expiration
        });
        }
```

[image: Apesar de que agregue el claim con el json, sigue sin aparecer.]

Comment: Para que vayas investigando (yo tampoco lo tengo 100% claro) las claims son siempre strings. Por lo tanto, podrias mandar un json como string en la claim, y serializarlo y descerializarlo segun la necesidad. Pero siempre viaja como string.

Comment: Cierto... la cosa es que al depurar, entre mis claims, no aparecen esos arreglos que si salen en la web de jwt.io (los de area, workstation y ciltspatk),esos son los que me interesa tomar.

Comment: Tal vez seria interesante ver que te aparece del lado de .net core.. una cosa es lo que te muestra una consola de debug y otra lo que llega... tal vez ya esta como json y la consola lo esta limpiando?

Comment: Voy a actualizar la pregunta con ese contenido.

Comment: Esa claim no incluye area (por ejemplo).. o sea que no lo estas recibiendo.. no lo definiste del lado de .net core...

Comment: Si no cual seria area?

Comment: ookei okei. ¿Y como puedo definirlo o en que parte?

Comment: Definilo como un string.. igual por lo que veo, estas probando algo en un sistema, y despues otra cosa en el tuyo.. si mandaras un string que fuera un json, despues podrias traducirlo de vuelta...

Comment: o capaz lo hace solo.. nunca lo probe.. que pasa si le queres pasar una lista a la claim? protesta?

Comment: Hola, te aconsejo leas este artículo que seguro te puede ayudar [JSON Web Token - Seguridad en servicios Web API de .NET Core](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/5/20/json-web-token-seguridad-en-servicios-web-api-de-net-core)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo primero es informarte que los `claim`  son de tipo `key/value pair` por lo que se deberían ser lo más simple posible y creo no se soporta establecer objetos complejos. Por ejemplo y me tomo la libertad de creer que `areasByUser` es una lista de objetos complejos que tiene una propiedad `Id`, para agregar en tus `claim` un array de elementos debes agregar cada elemento con el mismo nombre del `claim`. En tu caso

```
areasByUser.ForEach(area =>
{
     claims.Add(new Claim("Area", area.Id);
}) ;
```

Comment: También establece en tu Método `Configure` de tu clase `Startup` lo siguiente para evitar el mapping de tus claims. `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultOutboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();`

Comment: La cosa es que ya lo paso. Paso mis valores como un JSON, me intersa ahora obtener ese JSON de regreso.

Comment: Hola. Verifica la propiedad `HttpContext.User.Identities` para ver si tienes más de una collecion de `Identity claims`

Comment: Inclusive creo recordar que hay una propiedad `Claims` a nivel de `HttpContext.User`

Comment: @JoséHerreraAvila: Hola, te aconsejo leas este artículo que seguro te puede ayudar [JSON Web Token - Seguridad en servicios Web API de .NET Core](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/5/20/json-web-token-seguridad-en-servicios-web-api-de-net-core)

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo, estas llamando a la función `LoginBuildTokenAsync` donde agregas los Claims dentro del action de login y luego revisas el HttContext. No creo que funcione asi, ya que el HttpContext es el del actual request, no va a tener el token que estas armando.

Tenes que hacer el login y en el Chrome dev tools o postman (dependiendo que uses) toma el token y revisalo en jwt.io. Si tiene la info necesaria ya esta. Si estas en una web, con hacer cualquier otro request toda esa info debe ir en el request, si estas usando Postman copialo y ponelo en la pestaña de authentication.

Saludos!